Azure Web App Authentication Token in Backend
I have a PHP Azure Linux Web App deployed with Azure AD Authentication enabled. This works fine. My app has an admin page and I'd like to deny access to users who are not in the authorized list of users. I tried do this is in the backend code without success. However, the equivalent front end code works fine. I'm trying to understand why this is. The backend also has access to the Microsoft Graph API through an application service principal, so I wanted to use that to check if the user is in a particular Azure AD group.
I've removed all IP based access restrictions as I determined that the app could not access itself with these in place.
This is the simplest use case I could construct. I can capture the AppServiceAuthSession token and use it.  The code below has a JavaScript block that runs on the front end, and I have verified that it does what I want. But I'm wondering why the equivalent PHP code that is running on the back end returns HTTP 403 Access Denied? Is there a way to do this from the backend? The sites I've found thus far all seem to indicate that this approach should work.
<?php session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Access Control</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>User Information</h1>
  <div id="user-info"></div>
  <div id="error-message"></div>

  <script>
    async function getUserInfo() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/.auth/me', {
          method: 'GET',
          credentials: 'include', // Include cookies in the request
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        const userInfo = data[0]; // Assuming the response is an array with user info as the first element

        const userId = userInfo.user_id.toLowerCase();
        const allowedEmails = [
          'me@example.com',
          'myself@example.com',
          'i@example.com'
        ];
        if (!allowedEmails.includes(userId)) {
          throw new Error('403 Forbidden: You are not authorized to access this page');
        }
        document.getElementById('user-info').innerHTML = `
          <p>EMail: ${userInfo.user_id}</p>
          <p>Name: ${userInfo.user_claims.find(claim => claim.typ === 'name').val}</p>
        `;
      } catch (error) {
        document.getElementById('error-message').innerHTML = `<p>Error: ${error.message}</p>`;
      }
    }

    // Call the function to get user info when the page loads
    window.onload = getUserInfo;
  </script>
  <?php
  function getAuthenticatedUser()
  {
    $appServiceAuthSession = $_COOKIE['AppServiceAuthSession'] ?? null;
    if (!$appServiceAuthSession) {
      throw new \RuntimeException('AppServiceAuthSession cookie not found');
    }

    $url = 'https://app-example-com.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $appServiceAuthSession,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
      ],
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $response_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);

    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
      throw new \RuntimeException(curl_error($curl));
    }

    if ($response_code == 403) {
      throw new \RuntimeException('403 Forbidden: Access is denied');
    }

    if ($response_code >= 400) {
      throw new \RuntimeException('HTTP Error: ' . $response_code);
    }

    $userInfo = json_decode($response, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
      throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to decode JSON response');
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    return $userInfo[0]; // Assuming the response is an array with user info as the first element
  }

  try {
    $userInfo = getAuthenticatedUser();
    $userIdLowerCase = strtolower($userInfo['user_id']);

    // List of allowed email addresses
    $allowedEmails = [
      'me@example.com',
      'myself@example.com',
      'i@example.com'
   ];

    // Check if the lowercase user_id is in the list of allowed emails
    if (!in_array($userIdLowerCase, array_map('strtolower', $allowedEmails))) {
      http_response_code(403);
      echo "<p>403 Forbidden: You are not authorized to access this page</p>";
      exit;
    }

    echo "<p>EMail: " . htmlspecialchars($userInfo['user_id']) . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Name: " . htmlspecialchars(array_column($userInfo['user_claims'], 'val', 'typ')['name']) . "</p>";
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<p>Error: " . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()) . "</p>";
  }
  ?>
  </p>
</body>
<?php

session_destroy();
?>

</html>


Can you share your complete GitHub repo here?

This is from a private repo so I cannot share it. This is a standalone page not relying on my other code. The only other thing needed is an Azure Linux Web App with Azure AD authentication enabled on the app. Is there something else you're thinking of? Perhaps I can share snippets of the code.

I tried the below sample PHP code as the backend with Azure AD Authentication enabled, and users from the authorized list were successfully signed in after deploying it to an Azure Linux Web App.
Code :
callback.php :
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
session_start();

$tokenUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token';
$clientId = '<clientID>';
$clientSecret = '<clientSecret>';
$redirectUri = '<AzureWebAppURL>/callback.php';

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['state']) && $_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth_state']) {
        echo 'Invalid state parameter.';
        http_response_code(400);
        exit;
    }
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    $client = new Client(['verify' => false]);
    $tokenParams = [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id'     => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'code'          => $code,
            'redirect_uri'  => $redirectUri,
        ]
    ];
    try {
        $tokenResponse = $client->post($tokenUrl, $tokenParams);
        if ($tokenResponse->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            $tokenData = json_decode($tokenResponse->getBody(), true);
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $tokenData['access_token'];
            $userInfoUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';
            $userResponse = $client->get($userInfoUrl, [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $_SESSION['access_token']
                ]
            ]);
            $userData = json_decode($userResponse->getBody(), true);
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $userData['mail']; 
            $authorizedEmails = ['xxxxxxxxxx.com', 'xxxxxxxxxxx.com', 'xxxxxxxxxxx.com']; 
            if (in_array($_SESSION['user_email'], $authorizedEmails)) {
                echo "<h2>Access Token</h2>";
                echo "<p>" . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['access_token']) . "</p>";
                echo '<br><a href="adminpage.php">Go to Admin Page</a>';
            } else {
                echo "You do not have permission to access this page.";
                http_response_code(403);
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Error exchanging authorization code for access token: Unexpected response';
            http_response_code(500);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error exchanging authorization code for access token: ' . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage());
        http_response_code(500);
    }
} else {
    echo 'Authorization code not found.';
    http_response_code(400);
}
?>

adminpage.php:
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
session_start();
function isAuthenticatedAndAuthorized() {
    $authorizedEmails = ['xxxxxxxxxxx.com', 'xxxxxxxxxx.com', 'xxxxxxxxx.com']; 
    return isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && !empty($_SESSION['access_token']) &&
           isset($_SESSION['user_email']) && in_array($_SESSION['user_email'], $authorizedEmails);
}
if (!isAuthenticatedAndAuthorized()) {
    header("Location: auth.php");
    exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Admin Dashboard</h1>
    <p>Welcome, authorized user!</p>
    <br>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>

index.php :
<?php
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Microsoft OAuth Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Microsoft OAuth Example</h1>
    <a href="auth.php">Login with Microsoft</a> |
    <a href="adminpage.php">Admin Page</a>
</body>
</html>

auth.php :
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$authUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
$clientId = '<clientID>';
$redirectUri = '<AzureWebAppURL>/callback.php';
$scope = urlencode('User.Read email openid profile offline_access');
$state = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
session_start();
$_SESSION['oauth_state'] = $state;
$authorizationUrl = "$authUrl?client_id=$clientId&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirectUri) . "&response_type=code&scope=$scope&state=$state";
header("Location: $authorizationUrl");
exit;
?>

logout.php :
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = [];
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
?>

I added the following URL as a redirect URI in the Azure AD Authentication under the Web as shown below.
<AzureWebAppURL>/callback.php


Azure WebApp Output :

I got the access token after successfully logged in using the Login with Microsoft button as shown below,

Admin Page :

If a user without access tries to sign in, they will receive the following error.

